# Calculus of torque to move a small vehicle

Tags: torque

I have a to choose two DC motors in order to carry a vehicle. I assume that the mass of the whole vehicle (all components included) is **1Kg**, the surface is **flat and made of wood**, the wheel coupled to the motor has a **radius of 2.5cm** and that the motors are located on each side of the platform.

My first attempt is: the torque needed by each motor to start moving the object is

torque=(1Kg*9.8m/s^2)/2 x (0.025m)  x (static friction coef. plastic//wood)=0.05Nm,

with a static friction coef. plastic//wood = 0.4

Is this calculation the right one? I believe that the most demanding torque for the motors is the one, as the torque should be smaller when the robot is already in motion.

Thank you!